# Custom Page Template in external assembly in Sitefinity CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I have created a custom mvc page template in external assembly as custompagetemplate.cshtml and changed its BuildAction property to Embedded

[image]

Resource and made the entry in AssemblyInfo.cs.... But the template is not registered (it is not available in Sitefinity's Backend under Design/Page Templates).

I have gone through a link http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/knowledge-base/details/sitefinity-cannot-find-template-created-in-an-external-assembly

[image]

and I have made the virtual path entry but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `Mvc` folders are meant for custom MVC Widgets.
Sitefinity MVC (feather) uses the `ResourcePackages` folder for out-of-the-box widgets and layouts.

If you move your layout file to `/ResourcePackages/Bootstrap/MVC/Views/Layouts` it will automatically be added to the Page Design overview in Sitefinity Backend.